# Laravel - Edit role user by role_name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have made an edit page for my users and everything works except changing the role. I have made a select menu which displays all the roles through a foreach loop. And it displays the current role of the user like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="Datum">Rol:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <select class="form-control" id="Datum" name="role">
       <option selected>{{ $user->role->role_name }}</option>
       @foreach($roles as $role)
       <option>{{ $role->role_name }}</option>
       @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I want to be able to change the role by the role_name instead of ID. I honestly don't know where to look. How can I achieve this?

The controller that the form goes through looks like this:

```
public function updateUser(Request $request, $id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    $user->save();

    return back()->with('flash', 'Account is geupdate');
}
```

In the database, a user has a role_id and in the role table, it has all the roles. So the relations are: User has a Role, Role has many users. These relations are set in the models. So `{{ $user->role->role_name }}` works just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume **role_name** is unique. In your post method you can do the following-

```
public function updateUser(Request $request, $id)
{
        $role = Role::where('role_name','=',$request->input('role_name'))->first();
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->role_id = $role->id;
        $user->save();

       return back()->with('flash', 'Account is geupdate');
}
```

As per your comment, add this on your user model-

```
 public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{   
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Do you also when I change the password like this: `$user->password = $request->password;` how to hash it again? So that if I change his password the password gets hashed again?

Comment: i have edited my answer, look now. You don't need to worry about hashing on controller to save or update a new user after this.